# Node.js original variable for each user without using sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

How can I declare independend original variable for each user without using sessions and passing variables?

I had not problem with this in PHP, because variables are original for each user and you can share them between functions.

```
<?php
$original_variable_for_each_user = "foo";
function foo() {
   //it can reach variable
   console.log(original_variable_for_each_user);
}
?>
```

However I can not do this in Node.js, if I want to share variable between functions.

Situation 1

```
var not_original_variable_for_each_user = "foo";

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  not_original_variable_for_each_user = "foo";
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

function foo() {
  //it can reach variable
  console.log(not_original_variable_for_each_user);
}
```

Situation 2

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var original_variable_for_each_user = "foo"
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

function foo() {
  //it can not reach original_variable_for_each_user
  console.log(original_variable_for_each_user);
}
```

I will appreciate your answers.

Comment: What is the question exactly? What happens when you run your examples and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Situation 1 - variable declared as public, so it can be reach in other functions. However when you declare variable as public in node.js, variable can not be unique for each user, Situation 2 - variable is unique, but is not reachable from other functions, so it will throw error. I expect to have public variable, which can be unique for each user as in PHP.

Comment: A variable *per user* (and not just per request/connection) sounds *exactly* like a session variable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on global variables for state, pass the state around as a function argument.

Your second example can be rewritten as following:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var userState = {
        myVar: "foo",
    };
    foo(userState); // here the state is explicitly being passed into the function
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

function foo(userState) {
    console.log(userState.myVar);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But is it possible to do it without passing variable?

Comment: By using sessions, see for instance [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) (assuming you are using express, but the code looks like it is).